# AndroidManifest running on BlackBerry Q10

Tags: android, blackberry

I'm currently trying to run an Android application on a BlackBerry Q10. The application forces itself into landscape mode, but Q10 does not support it.

I've already tried changing the AndroidManifest.xml file (changing landscape mode to portrait mode), the splash screen runs perfectly in portrait mode, the rest won't load (screen turns black) because it still forces itself into landscape mode.

Can someone help me with this?

Regards